# How do I install a non-default theme?

Tags: theme

I am trying to add a second, non-default, theme to our storefront. I read how to properly identify the templates, css, etc. in the configuration settings, and I have copied over what seems to be the correct folder structure for my new theme, but I didn't actually install anything. Is this a step I have missed? All I really did was add a new folder and use that folder's name in the config settings.

Can someone help me figure out what I've done wrong?

Comment: Please clarify which files you copied where and how you configured your theme in the Magento backend. Did you buy a theme or do you want to create one yourself?

Comment: Yes we purchased Ultimo 1.6.1 theme and have that package up and running.

Default template file is here:
/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/page/html/header.phtml

I created a new file here:
/app/design/frontend/ultimo/pro/template/page/html/header.phtml

That's all I've added so far... I put some text in the page so I could see it working, but so far nothing.

In admin/system/configuration/Design, the package still uses "Ultimo" like our default theme, and I have changed "template," "skin," "layout," and "default" from "default" to "pro" (same name used in the folder structure).

Comment: Sounds good so far. I don't know if this particular theme does something different to the default theme (e.g. does it cache the header block?). I'd resort to the typical checks: check the filenames letter for letter, check the permissions of the new files, clear caches, check the log files, use the template hints to found out what's going on.